# angular 9.1 and babylon 4.1 loading gltf issue

Tags: angularjs, babylonjs

Day 1 on babylon.js. I have cloned [this](https://github.com/JohnnyDevNull/ng-babylon-template) repository for angular 9.1 and babylon 4.1 starter kit. I am able to run the project.

Next step is that I wanted to load the gltf model for which I have installed the package `babylonjs-loaders` and used the library but getting error that path to model 404.

Code:

```
    import { WindowRefService } from './../services/window-ref.service';
import {ElementRef, Injectable, NgZone} from '@angular/core';
import {
  Engine,
  FreeCamera,
  Scene,
  Light,
  Mesh,
  Color3,
  Color4,
  Vector3,
  HemisphericLight,
  StandardMaterial,
  Texture,
  DynamicTexture
} from 'babylonjs';
import 'babylonjs-materials';
import 'babylonjs-loaders';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class EngineService {
  private canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;
  private engine: BABYLON.Engine;
  private camera: BABYLON.FreeCamera;
  private scene: BABYLON.Scene;
  private light: BABYLON.Light;

  private sphere: Mesh;

  public constructor(
    private ngZone: NgZone,
    private windowRef: WindowRefService
  ) {}


  public animate(): void {
    // We have to run this outside angular zones,
    // because it could trigger heavy changeDetection cycles.
    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      const rendererLoopCallback = () => {
        this.scene.render();
      };

      if (this.windowRef.document.readyState !== 'loading') {
        this.engine.runRenderLoop(rendererLoopCallback);
      } else {
        this.windowRef.window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
          this.engine.runRenderLoop(rendererLoopCallback);
        });
      }

      this.windowRef.window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
        this.engine.resize();
      });
    });
  }



  public loadScene(canvas: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>): void {
    // The first step is to get the reference of the canvas element from our HTML document
    this.canvas = canvas.nativeElement;

    // Then, load the Babylon 3D engine:
    this.engine = new BABYLON.Engine(this.canvas,  true);

    // create a basic BJS Scene object
    this.scene = new BABYLON.Scene(this.engine);
    this.scene.clearColor = new Color4(0, 0, 0, 0);

    // create a FreeCamera, and set its position to (x:5, y:10, z:-20 )
    this.camera = new BABYLON.FreeCamera('camera1', new BABYLON.Vector3(5, 10, -20), this.scene);

    // target the camera to scene origin
    this.camera.setTarget(BABYLON.Vector3.Zero());

    // attach the camera to the canvas
    this.camera.attachControl(this.canvas, false);

    // create a basic light, aiming 0,1,0 - meaning, to the sky
    this.light = new BABYLON.HemisphericLight('light1', new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 1, 0), this.scene);

    BABYLON.SceneLoader.Append("./", "bmw.gltf", this.scene, function (scene) {
    // do something with the scene

  });
  }
}
```

I have googled on similar question but did not reach to any conclusion. I might be missing something basic. I have kept the gltf on the same directory as ts file and path is proper. I have tested with putting png image on same path and able to see it in network tab of chrome dev tool with 200 status.

Please help guys. I am guessing the way i am importing babylonjs-loaders is the culprit here.

error screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your bmw.gltf file should be located in your assets folder.
this means that you will have to load the files from there.

```
BABYLON.SceneLoader.Append("/assets", "bmw.gltf"
```